# Hover menu effect and scrolling

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've found amazing hover menu script written by a user of Codepen, but I encountered problem which I can't solve myself. I'm hoping that anyone here can help me with it. I would really appreciate it.

The Problem is that if I want to add content making website scrollable and after we scroll it down the fixed Gooey Hover Effect which should stick to mouse position scroll down itself and doesn't follow mouse pointer anymore.

The Code

Here the link to the [Codepen](http://codepen.io/kejlos/pen/jVvOXM)

HTML

```
<div id="menu">
    <div class="hamburger">
        <div class="line"></div>
        <div class="line"></div>
        <div class="line"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="menu-inner">

        <ul>
            <li>Menu Item</li>
            <li>Menu Item</li>
            <li>Menu Item</li>
            <li>Menu Item</li>
            <li>Menu Item</li>
            <li>Menu Item</li>
        </ul>
    </div>



    <svg version="1.1" id="blob"xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
        <path id="blob-path" d="M60,500H0V0h60c0,0,20,172,20,250S60,900,60,500z"/>
    </svg>
</div>
```

CSS

```
        body, html {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        background-color:#26394E ;
    }

    #menu {
        height: 100%;
        position: fixed;
        background-color: #FED057;
        width: 300px;
        transition: 1000ms all cubic-bezier(0.19, 1, 0.22, 1);
        transform: translateX(-100%);
        left: 60px;
    }

    #menu.expanded {
        transform: translateX(0%);
        left: 0px;
    }

    .menu-inner {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        position: relative;
    }

    #blob {
        top: 0;
        z-index: -1;
        right: 60px;
        transform: translateX(100%);
        height: 100%;
        position: absolute;
    }

    #blob-path {
        height: 100%;
        fill:  #FED057;
    }

    .hamburger {
        right: 20px;
        position: absolute;
        width: 20px;
        height: 20px;
        margin-top: -10px;  
    }

    .hamburger .line {
        width: 100%;
        height: 4px;
        background-color: #fff;
        position: absolute;
    }

    .hamburger .line:nth-child(2) {
        top: 50%;
        margin-top: -2px;
    }

    .hamburger .line:nth-child(3) {
        bottom: 0;
    }

    h1 {
        position: fixed;
        right: 0;
        margin: 0;
    }

    ul {
        padding: 0;
        list-style: none;
        width: 80%;
        margin-left: 10%;
        position: absolute;
        top: 10px;
    }

    ul li {
        color: #fff;
        font-family: sans-serif;
        padding: 20px 0;
    }

    p {
        position: absolute;
       left: 10%;
  color: #fff;
        margin: 0;
  width: 500px;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-weight: 100;
    }
```

JS

```
$(window).load(function(){
var height = window.innerHeight,
x= 0, 
y= height/2,
curveX = 10,
curveY = 0,
targetX = 0,
xitteration = 0,
yitteration = 0,
menuExpanded = false;

blob = $('#blob'),
blobPath = $('#blob-path'),

hamburger = $('.hamburger');

$(this).on('mousemove', function(e){
    x = e.pageX;

    y = e.pageY;
});

$('.hamburger, .menu-inner').on('mouseenter', function(){
    $(this).parent().addClass('expanded');
    menuExpanded = true;
});

$('.menu-inner').on('mouseleave', function(){
    menuExpanded = false;
    $(this).parent().removeClass('expanded');
});

function easeOutExpo(currentIteration, startValue, changeInValue, totalIterations) {
    return changeInValue * (-Math.pow(2, -10 * currentIteration / totalIterations) + 1) + startValue;
}

var hoverZone = 150;
var expandAmount = 20;

function svgCurve() {
    if ((curveX > x-1) && (curveX < x+1)) {
        xitteration = 0;
    } else {
        if (menuExpanded) {
            targetX = 0;
        } else {
            xitteration = 0;
            if (x > hoverZone) {
                targetX = 0;
            } else {
                targetX = -(((60+expandAmount)/100)*(x-hoverZone));
            }           
        }
        xitteration++;
    }

    if ((curveY > y-1) && (curveY < y+1)) {
        yitteration = 0;
    } else {
        yitteration = 0;
        yitteration++;  
    }

    curveX = easeOutExpo(xitteration, curveX, targetX-curveX, 100);
    curveY = easeOutExpo(yitteration, curveY, y-curveY, 100);

    var anchorDistance = 200;
    var curviness = anchorDistance - 40;

    var newCurve2 = "M60,"+height+"H0V0h60v"+(curveY-anchorDistance)+"c0,"+curviness+","+curveX+","+curviness+","+curveX+","+anchorDistance+"S60,"+(curveY)+",60,"+(curveY+(anchorDistance*2))+"V"+height+"z";

    blobPath.attr('d', newCurve2);

    blob.width(curveX+60);

    hamburger.css('transform', 'translate('+curveX+'px, '+curveY+'px)');

$('h2').css('transform', 'translateY('+curveY+'px)');
    window.requestAnimationFrame(svgCurve);
}

window.requestAnimationFrame(svgCurve);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here problem is `pageY` is counting in relative to `body` not in relative to `window`.

In place of `countY` I have uses `(y - window.scrollY)` several places and its worked.

**Javascript** code is here

```js
$(window).load(function(){
    var height = window.innerHeight,
  x= 0, y= height/2,
    curveX = 10,
    curveY = 0,
    targetX = 0,
    xitteration = 0,
    yitteration = 0,
    menuExpanded = false;

    blob = $('#blob'),
    blobPath = $('#blob-path'),

    hamburger = $('.hamburger');

    $(this).on('mousemove', function(e){
        x = e.pageX - window.scrollX;

        y = e.pageY - window.scrollX;
    });

    $('.hamburger, .menu-inner').on('mouseenter', function(){
        $(this).parent().addClass('expanded');
        menuExpanded = true;
    });

    $('.menu-inner').on('mouseleave', function(){
        menuExpanded = false;
        $(this).parent().removeClass('expanded');
    });

    function easeOutExpo(currentIteration, startValue, changeInValue, totalIterations) {
        return changeInValue * (-Math.pow(2, -10 * currentIteration / totalIterations) + 1) + startValue;
    }

    var hoverZone = 150;
    var expandAmount = 20;

    function svgCurve() {
        if ((curveX > x-1) && (curveX < x+1)) {
            xitteration = 0;
        } else {
            if (menuExpanded) {
                targetX = 0;
            } else {
                xitteration = 0;
                if (x > hoverZone) {
                    targetX = 0;
                } else {
                    targetX = -(((60+expandAmount)/100)*(x-hoverZone));
                }           
            }
            xitteration++;
        }

        if ((curveY > y-1) && (curveY < y+1)) {
            yitteration = 0;
        } else {
            yitteration = 0;
            yitteration++;  
        }

        curveX = easeOutExpo(xitteration, curveX, targetX-curveX, 100);
        curveY = easeOutExpo(yitteration, curveY, y-curveY, 100);

        var anchorDistance = 200;
        var curviness = anchorDistance - 40;

        var newCurve2 = "M60,"+height+"H0V0h60v"+((y -  window.scrollY)-anchorDistance)+"c0,"+curviness+","+curveX+","+curviness+","+curveX+","+anchorDistance+"S60,"+(curveY)+",60,"+((y -  window.scrollY)+(anchorDistance*2))+"V"+height+"z";

        blobPath.attr('d', newCurve2);

        blob.width(curveX+60);
        hamburger.css('transform', 'translate('+curveX+'px, '+(y -  window.scrollY)+'px)');

    $('h2').css('transform', 'translateY('+curveY+'px)');
        window.requestAnimationFrame(svgCurve);
    }

    window.requestAnimationFrame(svgCurve);

});
```

Comment: Thank you very much!! You're my hero. It works perfect.